# Is there a way to disable .ignoresSafeArea() on command in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am looking for a way to disable .ignoresSafeArea on command in SwiftUI. I cannot seem to find anyway of doing this currently. Is it possible?

Here is an example of where I would use it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var ignoresSafeArea: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                content
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can conditionally apply modifiers on swiftui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.

`ignoresSafeArea` has a parameter `edges`. Fortunately `Edge.Set` conforms to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` so you can pass an empty array for *don't ignore* and `.all` for *ignore*

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var ignoresSafeArea = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                content
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: ignoresSafeArea ? .all : [])
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple environment to test it

```
struct SomeView : View {
    @State private var ignoresSafeArea = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            Button(ignoresSafeArea ? "Don't ignore" : "Ignore") {
                withAnimation {
                    ignoresSafeArea.toggle()
                }
                
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: ignoresSafeArea ? .all : [])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

vadian provides a better answer specifically for this problem, one which is far more elegant and that didn't occur to me before taking the following approach.  But seeing as I have gone this way, a more generic solution might be useful for others in the future, so I'll post it anyway!

This is a bit of an old hack from the early days of SwiftUI, but I'm not yet aware of any "cleaner" ways to do it.

First, extend `View` to take an `if` method.  [Note the backticks to allow "if" to be reused.  You may wish to rename it]

```
extension View {
   @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, apply transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
       if condition {
         transform(self)
      } else {
         self
      }
   }
}
```

Then use this with a State property to control the application of the modifier.  A simple example of its use:

```
struct SimpleView: View {
   @State var showBackground = false
   var body: some View {
      Text("Hello, world!")/
         .if(showBackground) {
            view in
            view.background(.red)
         }
      Button("Toggle"){showBackground.toggle()}
   }
}
```

You could also modify the method to replace the condition parameter with an `@Autoclosure () -> Bool` which would allow the method to take an inline closure rather than a direct Bool.

The downside of either approach is that they return multiple Views which will limit the animations between them.